# How to run it during downtime?

Tags: python, automation

Currently, when it eventually matches the `time_defined` then runs the code in the if statement.

Would like to put this. What would be the proper approach to doing so?

Also, any suggestions on optimization are welcomed as well.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The best and easiest way to do this is to convert your python function into an AWS Lambda python function (easy), and then use AWS Cloudwatch events to trigger the function at whatever time interval you want (also easy).

> **What is Amazon CloudWatch Events**?
>
> Amazon CloudWatch Events delivers a near real-time stream of system
>   events that describe changes in Amazon Web Services (AWS) resources to
>   Amazon EC2 instances, **AWS Lambda functions**, Amazon Kinesis streams,
>   Amazon ECS tasks, Step Functions state machines, Amazon SNS topics,
>   Amazon SQS queues, or built-in targets. **Using simple rules that you
>   can quickly set up, you can match events and route them to one or more
>   target functions** or streams.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html

Comment: appreciate the response. Before upvoting/accepting, do you mind showing an example of AWS Cloudwatch for AWS Lambda python?

Comment: Here is an example: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/get-started-create-function.html a python Lambda function is 99% just regular python code with a few changes required to get it to work in Lambda, i.e. identifying the handler function.

Comment: You can change the trigger to a shorter interval for testing - and set it back when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that you need to do for this.
you need to create a wrapper script (let's say "wrap.py") as follows and set is in crontab for the AWS Server:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

python your_script_path.py
```

the first line mentions python path in your AWS Server installation with second line mentioning your script name that you want to run.

Please follow : https://superuser.com/a/682142 for more details.

Update: add cron job running "crontab -e" on shell

```
*     *     *   *    *        command to be executed
-     -     -   -    -
|     |     |   |    |
|     |     |   |    +----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
|     |     |   +------- month (1 - 12)
|     |     +--------- day of        month (1 - 31)
|     +----------- hour (0 - 23)
+------------- min (0 - 59)
```

Comment: Do you mind showing an example with the code I provided? Thank you in advance

Comment: What type of example you want? just create the script wrap.py with name of your python file and add to cronjob on the AWS server.

Comment: Do you want me to tell you the crontab line which you should to add to AWS?

Comment: Yes, that'd be great, and if you can elaborate on the process, e.g. scheduling time, would be helpful too. New to the crontab.

Comment: Did you look at the link I mentioned? setting up the crontab is detailed in that link. here it is again https://superuser.com/questions/682141/setting-up-a-python-cron-job.